# keep nohup going after warning

Tags: hive, nohup

I have a command that uses hive but there is a problem in hive that displays a warning while loading up. hive always says this when I load it:

```
2017-01-05 18:14:29,163 WARN  [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: The hbase-prefix-tree module jar containing PrefixTreeCodec is not present.  Continuing without it.
```

This is just a hive issue but hasn't been fixed and you cannot suppress this warning for some reason. Why does nohup quit when this warning happens?

Comment: I figured it out, you have to use this: export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding,

You can try:  **nohup *your-command* >test.out 2>test.logs &**

OR

you can redirect your logs to /dev/null in case you dont want them.

You can try:  **nohup *your-command* >test.out 2>/dev/null &**

Let me know if you are looking for something else?

~Kedar